# null / nil in swift language

Tags: ios, swift

How would we define the following in swift programming language :

- null
- nil
- Nil
- [NSNull null]

In other words, what would be the swift equivalent of each of these objective c terms.
Besides, would also like to know whether any specific use cases exist for non objective c types like structs and enums.

Comment: The question tagged is about "possibly missing values ", whereas I am interested in the different types /variations of these. Related, but not duplicate.

Comment: You'll find that they are one in the same.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Regarding equivalents:

- `NULL` has no equivalent in Swift.
- `nil` is also called `nil` in Swift
- `Nil` has no equivalent in Swift
- `[NSNull null]` can be accessed in Swift as NSNull()

Note: These are my guesses based on reading and play. Corrections welcome.

But nil/NULL handling in Swift is very different from Objective C. It looks designed to enforce safety and care. Read up on [optionals in the manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-XID_1011). Generally speaking a variable can't be NULL at all and when you need to represent the "absence of a value" you do so declaratively.

Comment: How would you declare absence of value to check against? like == nil of Objective-c

Comment: @JuanPabloBoero See my response below

Comment: NULL in Obj-C means “a zero pointer for use with plain-C”.  Since Swift is compatible with C libraries, @Rien's answer below is the best answer I know of for `NULL`'s equivalent.

Answer (score 22):

If you need to use a NULL at low level pointer operations, use the following:

```
UnsafePointer<Int8>.null()
```

Comment: I get 'has no member null'.

Answer (score 13):

`nil` means "no value" but is completely distinct in every other sense from Objective-C's `nil`.

It is assignable only to optional variables. It works with both literals and structs (i.e. it works with stack-based items, not just heap-based items).

Non-optional variables cannot be assigned `nil` even if they're classes (i.e. they live on the heap).

So it's explicitly not a `NULL` pointer and not similar to one. It shares the name because it is intended to be used for the same semantic reason.

Answer (score 8):

Swift’s `nil` is not the same as `nil` in Objective-C.
In Objective-C, `nil` is a pointer to a non-existent object. In Swift, `nil` is not a pointer—it is the absence of a value of a certain type. Optionals of any type can be set to `nil`, not just object types.

- `NULL` has no equivalent in Swift.
- `nil` is also called nil in Swift
- `Nil` has no equivalent in Swift
- `[NSNull null]` can be accessed in Swift as `NSNull()`

Answer (score 5):

The concept of Null in Swift resumes to the Optional enum. The enum is defined like this

```
enum Optional<T> {
  case Some(T)
  case None
}
```

What this means is that you cannot have an uninitialised variable/constant in Swift.. If you try to do this, you will get a compiler error saying that the variable/constant cannot be uninitialised. You will need to wrap it in the Optional enum..

This is the only Null concept you will find in Swift

Answer (score 0):

```
if !(myDATA is NSNull) {
// optional is NOT NULL, neither NIL nor NSNull
} else {
// null
}
```