# Java null vs Swift nil

Tags: ios, swift, null

I'm coming from a Java/Android background where we use `NULL`. Now I am doing Swift/iOS and I am confused as to what Swift's `nil` means.

Can I use it like NULL in Java? Does it act the exact same way or is there something different about its usage?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24043722/183181

Comment: Possible duplicate of [null / nil in swift language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043589/null-nil-in-swift-language)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can think of 'null' and 'nil' the same. Whether the language includes optionals is a separate concern.

Objective-C, has 'nil', but does not have in-built optionals while Swift does. Similarly, Java has 'null', but not have implicit optionals, while several JVM languages such as Kotlin, Scala and Ceylon do, and did so before Swift. &nbsp

Here's an article that compares about null, nil and optionals in Kotlin, Scala and Swift: http://codemonkeyism.com/comparing-optionals-and-null-in-swift-scala-ceylon-and-kotlin/

Incidentally, for Android development you may want to investigate [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/) and the associated [Anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko) library from Jetbrains.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift does not currently support a null coalescing operator.**

**Swift nil explanation**

`nil` means "no value". Non-optional variables cannot be assigned `nil` even if they're classes, so it's explicitly not a `null` pointer and not similar to one.

I can recommend you to read more about [optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-XID_1011) in Swift.

Comment: No, actually, it's not equivalent. Definitely read the optionals link.

Comment: @JackLawrence how is it not equivalent. You have peaked my interest. I think the only difference lies in what it can be assigned to, but it has the same semantic meaning. And if everything in Java was like original obj-c and considered an implicitly unwrapped optional, they'd be the same.

Comment: You´re right read more about it and learned it now. @sylvanaar check the updated answer.

Comment: I suppose it only has meaning in relation to optionals. I guess that makes it different enough.

Comment: Exactly. +1'd the edited answer. `Optional` is an enum and `nil` is just a faster way of typing `Optional.None`.

Comment: I think you're arguing over semantics.  `null` in Java is a type, which can be cast to any non-primitive reference type; `nil` can also be cast to any reference type, provided it is declared an optional.  The primary difference is more about the setup of the variable, rather than the null/nil value.  By-and-large the null/nil are mostly the same (a lack of value, that isn't 0), but the rules in how they can be assigned are slightly different between Java and Swift.

Comment: @vol7ron "By-and-large the null/nil are mostly the same (a lack of value, that isn't 0)" is the kind of answer I was looking for. I just really need to know if I can just think of null/nil the same as I go forward learning swift and eventually am making the same app for android/ios.

Comment: @MicroR Swift does not currently support a null coalescing operator. Check the updated answer.

Comment: The main difference between `null` and `nil` is that trying to, say, call methods on `nil` is perfectly legal (if you mark them as optional), while doing the same in Java results in a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1):

Disclosure: I don't know a whole terrible lot about Java, so my answer is coming from a C++/Objective-C/Swift perspective.

Matt Thompson of [NSHipster](https://nshipster.com/) has a great post about it and how it relates to Objective-C vs C. You can find it [here](https://nshipster.com/nil/).

The answer basically boils down to this: you should consider it the same.

- `0` is how you represent nothing for a primitive value
- `NULL` is how you represent nothing for literal for C pointers
- `nil` is how you represent nothing for literal Objective-C/Swift objects