# how to pass a nil value for one of the parameter in alamofire Post request

Tags: swift, post, parameters, alamofire

I would like to pass a nil value i.e., optional to one of the parameter value. And it must proceed with the nil value in the **Alamofire Post request** .It would be helpful if you tell me how to proceed next?

```
    let image: UIImage = UIImage()
    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
    let base64String = imageData?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)

    let parameters = [
        "first_name": "XXXXX",
        "email" : "1234@gmail.com",
        "password" : "password",
        "profile_picture" : base64String]

Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://abc/public/user/register", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON, headers: nil)

        .progress { bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite in
            print(totalBytesWritten)

            // This closure is NOT called on the main queue for performance
            // reasons. To update your ui, dispatch to the main queue.
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                print("Total bytes written on main queue: \(totalBytesWritten)")
           }
        }
        .responseJSON { response in
            debugPrint(response)
    }
```

The response should gets succeeded even if the **profile_pictures** is empty. I know it can be done with optional chaining but don't know how to proceed!!

Answer (score 7):

By passing nil or uninitialized optional parameter Server will get Optional

You can pass NSNull() to dictionary

try this, like

```
var params = ["paramA","valueA"] if imageBase64 == nil {   parms["image"] = NSNull()} else {   params["image"] = imageBase64 }
```

swiftyjson also handle null as NSNull

also there is good reference here
[null / nil in swift language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043589/null-nil-in-swift-language)

Comment: I couldn't get you, could you implement your scenario in my code for a better understanding.

Comment: @PraveenKumar If no image is available you want key must be there with null value?

Comment: It says cannot assign a value of type 'NSNull' to type 'String' at this line `parms["image"] = NSNull()`

Comment: `var params = ["paramA","valueA","image":NSNull()]` working in playground try AnyObject! value then

Answer (score 1):

I think your simplest answer would be to add `"profile_picture"` as a second step.

```
var parameters = [
    "first_name": "XXXXX",
    "email" : "1234@gmail.com",
    "password" : "password"]

if let base64String = base64String where !base64String.isEmpty {
    parameters["profile_picture"] = base64String
}
```

Comment: it works man!! But if i assign a valid image, it shows the same result that no image is available.

Answer (score -1):

hope this will help you :)

```
var parameters :[String : AnyObject?] = [
    "first_name": "XXXXX",
    "email" : "1234@gmail.com",
    "password" : "password"]

if let string = base64String where base64String.isEmpty != false {
  parameters["profile_picture"] = string 
}
```

Comment: @ Sahil `"key": nil` this will be treated as an additional [Key:Value] pair. What it is supposed to do with the "profile_picture" value?!

Comment: okay, you mean when you base64String is empty you wana pass nil?

Comment: Yes it should, but it gets crashed while unwrapping the value, because it is a nil value. I need to get a success response even if the value is nil. When i tried your code, it says  **'valye of type 'Bool' can never be nil, comparison isn't allowed'**

Comment: sorry for that. isEmpty either return false or true

Comment: It works!! but if i give a valid image it shows the same result in my response that no image is available.

Comment: what is your base64String value?  i mean did you debug your code?

Comment: It is a huge encoded string like 8RhCyHNWMoZaZjnv7emSezx.... so on. yes i debug the code and i get the nil value if there is no image and i get this string value if there is a valid image but in my response it is not getting reflected. Do i need to move on to the **Upload Post request**  or can i do it here itself?!

Comment: i guess you should use Upload method.

Comment: then you need to ask server guy. and you should try hitting api in postman.

Answer (score -1):

After a very thorough research, I found out it can be done easily through optional chaining and type casting.

The first step it to divide the parameters by type casting it to **string** and **Image** and check for the availability of String value and Image value.

```
let parameters: [String : AnyObject? ] = [
    "first_name": "XXXXX",
    "email" : "1234@gmail.com",
    "password" : "password",
    "profile_pic" : UIImage(named: "logo")]
```

Do it like this in the request method

```
for (key, value) in parameters {

                if let value1 = value as? String {
                    multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: value1.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: key)
                }
                if let value1 = value as? UIImage {
                  let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(value1, 1)
                      multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData!, name: key, fileName: "logo.png" , mimeType: "image/png")
                    }
```

You don't have to split the parameters into two, one for the string values and other for the image and also it is unnecessary to convert the image to string. Hope this solution helps!!