# CGPathMoveToPoint have some trouble in creating path

Tags: ios, swift, cgpath, xcode8

I a using following code to create path from `CGPoint` array().

```
public func creatPath (for points:[CGPoint]) {
    let path = CGMutablePath()
    let startPoint = points.first

    CGPathMoveToPoint( path, CGAffineTransform.identity, startPoint.x, startPoint.y)

    var index = 0
    for point in points {
        if index == 0 { continue }
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, points.x, points.y)
        index += 1
    }
    path.closeSubpath()
}
```

But it always end up showing me following error:

> nil is not compatible with expected argument type UnsafePointer `<CGAffineTransForm>`

I have also tried using `CGAffineTransform.identity` Then it shows:

> Cannot convert value of type 'CGAffineTransform' to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer`<CGAffineTransform>`'

I am not sure what else can we use here. I am using Xcode8 beta 6. Swift 3.0

**Edit:** When I try:-

```
var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity as CGAffineTransform;
CGPathMoveToPoint( path, &transform, startPoint.x, startPoint.y)
```

It shows:

> 'CGPathMoveToPoint' is unavailable: Use move(to:transform:)

And while trying:

```
CGPathMoveToPoint( path, NSNull(), startPoint.x, startPoint.y)
```

> *Error is:* Cannot convert value of type 'NSNull' to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer'

Comment: It's because in Objective-C, we do: `CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity; CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, &transform, point.x, point.y);` with the "&var" stuff. If you want to pass `NULL`, apparently you can do like that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27169902/1801544 (I don't speak Swift, I'm just pointing out possible solutions/hints).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift 3 has a much improved, object-oriented interface for `CGMutablePath`. Best of all: the *transform* parameter has a default value and can be omitted.

```
public func creatPath (for points:[CGPoint]) {
    let path = CGMutablePath()
    let startPoint = points.first

    path.move(to: startPoint)

    var index = 0
    for point in points {
        if index == 0 { continue }
        path.addLine(to: point)
        index += 1
    }
    path.closeSubpath()
}
```

Note: I've changed the loop variable from `points` to `point` to avoid to collision with the parameter name.

**Update**

You can simplify your code:

```
public func creatPath (for points:[CGPoint]) {
    let path = CGMutablePath()
    path.addLines(between: points)
    path.closeSubpath()
}
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you very much for the help! Where can I get the documentation of Swift3? As https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPathCreateMutable still have it for Swift2.x, I guess.

Comment: I'm also confused about the documentation as there is old and new one out there. Have a look at [CGMutablePath - Core Graphics](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgmutablepath). It covers the Swift 3 syntax but has hardly any description.